# PyQT: OS X Full Screen Mode?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I've got an open source PyQT app, and am wanting to know if it's possible to have it enter "full screen" like other OS X Mountain Lion apps do; meaning like Safari full screen.

Or is this impossible at the moment?